# How to display a wait cursor and a message Loading when popup opens

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am executing few functions while opening a popup.
It takes 2-3 secs so I want to add some message loading and change the cursor to wait/progress till the popup opens.

How to acheive this in jquery/js?

**Edited**

```
$('#open_fancy_popup').click(function(){
     $("body").css("cursor","wait");
     updateDropDown();
     updateRows();
     populate();
     enableCheckbox();  
    $("body").css("cursor","initial");                  
});
```

I tried this :

```
<div id="WaitDialog"   class="hidden" style="text-align: center">
        <img  src="css/images/loading_black.gif" />
        <div style="margin-top: 10px; color: white">
            <b>Please wait</b>
        </div>
    </div>
```

and added  `$("#WaitDialog").modalDialog();`before all the functions but it didnt work?
Is there any simple solution to this problem ?

Answer (score 1):

You can simply add with jquery css function a cursor:pointer to body selector and then take it out when your function finishes.

Like:

```
$("body").css("cursor", "wait");
```

Comment: where to add this ? inside the click function ?

Comment: Or create a class like `.wait { cursor: wait; }` and apply massively to all elements with jQuery: `$('*').toggleClass('wait')`.

Comment: yes, this at start and second at end

$("body").css("cursor","initial");

Comment: why to add to all elements if you can add to one :) but idea with predefining class is good too

Comment: Applying the class to the body doesn't cover some elements like form elements (inputs, buttons, etc).

Comment: You are right! Thanks for that tip.

Btw, toggleClass is risky (in example if someone pushes esc and refresh or sth). I recommend to add class at start and remove at end (or in callback).

Comment: I changed but it didnt work.If I add only wait cursor it changes after popup comes. I want to show it when the button is clicked and changes to default when the popup comes.

Comment: so add that css cursor wait with separate jquery:

`$('#open_fancy_popup').mousedown(function(){
   $('*').addClass('wait'); //ofcourse you must declare this class first
   });`

and add 
`$('*').removeClass('wait');`
 at end of your function (where u made body cursor initial)

Comment: it doesnt go into the function mouse down. go directly to the click

Comment: $('#open_fancy_popup').mousedown(function(){ 
                $('*').addClass('wait'); 
            });